# ActionView::Template::Error (no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I am working on ROR app with Mongodb.App is working fine on localhost, but when i deploy it in heroku i am getting error. One of my view file command is this:

```
@h=Portfolio.last.folders
<%= @h%>
```

The Portfolio is a collection with field folders as array. Mongodb on production contain this.
Even i try do same in heroku rails console I got the same error which is :

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:35:in `+'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:35:in `digest'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:47:in `build_auth_command'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb:25:in `initialize'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/node.rb:488:in `new'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/node.rb:488:in `login'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/node.rb:48:in `block in apply_auth'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/node.rb:47:in `each'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/node.rb:47:in `apply_auth'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/cluster.rb:250:in `with_secondary'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/session/context.rb:104:in `with_node'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/session/context.rb:43:in `query'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/query.rb:115:in `first'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongoid-3.0.15/lib/mongoid/contextual/mongo.rb:233:in `last'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongoid-3.0.15/lib/mongoid/contextual.rb:18:in `last'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/mongoid-3.0.15/lib/mongoid/finders.rb:129:in `last'
from (irb):2
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
```

In development machine I can do this in console. Any guesses why this error on heroku.

Comment: Just a guess, but the stacktrace seems to be pointing at this error occurring in: 'build_auth_command' and 'digest'
in moped. Are you authenticating in the same way as your local version?

Comment: In my local_host i have mongodb installed locally , whereas on heroku i am using monhohq add on which has collections? I am nw to mongodb what is this build_auth_command'

Comment: Your stacktrace is specifically complaining about authenticating via moped... that's where to start looking (sorry, I'm actually unfamiliar with mongo, so can't be more specific).

Comment: can you please put your view code...you got error on moped gem `moped-1.4.3/lib/moped/protocol/commands/authenticate.rb`

Comment: The view code mainly contain two line which I have written rest are using the @h variable to show different things.

Comment: `no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String` this error are coming when you want to concat a fixnum into string as like `s = "I want"+12+"$"` it will throw this error as `12` is fixnum and I want to concat it in String that is not possible

Comment: I have this exact same problem when I run rails locally, and connect to a mongo database hosted on MongoHQ and provisioned through Heroku. Interestingly, if I hammer refresh it will sometimes run fine every few requests. So it may be a problem on MongoHQ, or connecting to their server... did you ever come up with a solution?

Comment: @genkilabs yes, basically there was an authentication issue with MongoHQ as I used numeral in password when I changed it to string it works, you can try mongodirector for validation with heroku.