# Heroku Mongodb setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, heroku, mongoid

I am working on ROR app with Mongodb.I am deploying app on heroku , the mapper i am using is mongoid.
This is my confiq.yml

```
production:
 # Configure available database sessions. (required)
 sessions:
# Defines the default session. (required)
default:
  # Defines the name of the default database that Mongoid can connect to.
  # (required).
  database: app17040252
  username: heroku
  password: XYZ
  # Provides the hosts the default session can connect to. Must be an array
  # of host:port pairs. (required)
  hosts:
    - dharma.mongohq.com:10069
```

I have few doubts
1)I wanted to know in the Password field- actual password will come or display password provided by mongohq?
2)Is I am missing anything in the confiq.yml>
3)will mongoid works fine with ruby 2.0.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The password field should be the mongohq password. You should get one when you create the database in there.

2) the config looks almost right to me, just the indentation is a little off. the `default` entry must be under `sessions` entry.

3) mongoid is tested on ruby 2.0.0, and used both together in production without any problem, so it should be just fine.

Comment: Hey I am doing this only but i am getting this error http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18733507/actionviewtemplateerror-no-implicit-conversion-of-fixnum-into-string-on-her and in local host everything works fine with local mongodb